# Mathematica: Implementation of Partial Least Squares (PLS)?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-mining, least-squares, mathematica-8, data-fitting

I'm looking for a PLS implementation for Wolfram Mathematica.
I just cant seem to find any implementation for it - do you know one? In general, I'm a bit confused that there exist only so few third-party packages/libraries for mathematica in general :(

For now I probably will just use `RLink` in mathematica to be able to refer to the R package `pls` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/index.html) but a direct implementation in mathematica would be nicer for debugging and testing purposes...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67282/implementation-of-partial-least-squares-pls